# How to customize google claim mapping?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, google-oauth, wso2-identity-server

I finished logging in API-M via google credential.

I use Just-In-Time provisioning to provision user with google profile, but I can't customize the claim.

While the user is provisioned, the user ID is always the email, but what I need is account id (sub).

I try to remove the email from scope, the user ID will be account id(sub), but I won't get email anymore.

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add sub as subject attribute in both IDP and SP configurations.
Then it will pick as subject for JIT provisioning.

Thanks
Isura

Comment: I tried but it failed. The user id is still the email. I try to use the oauth2/openid configuration to google but the problem is I can only get openid and email , no profile.

Comment: Can you attach your configurations, claim mappings in both IDP and SP?

Comment: I think the google claim mapping was written in the wso2 class, so I can't modify it.Now I decide I won't provision user who is from 3rd party account.Thanks so much.